# Microsoft azure database connect from shared hosting

Tags: c#, database, azure, hosting

I am hosting my site on a shared server and wants to move my database to azure for better manageability. I created a database and added some data on azure platform. I tried to connect to that database through my local computer and it works. But when I am trying the same connection string on a shared hosting servers it gives me resource not found 505 error. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons when you setup an Azure SQL DB it only allows connections from IP Addresses that you specify. Before recent enhancements to the portal, this required you to manually add your local IP Address and a loopback for anything hosted on Azure.

Since you are hosting your web site on a 3rd party provider you probably just need to find out the IP Address where your site is hosted and add that to the 'whitelist' of IP addresses that Azure SQL DB maintains. After you do that, it should just work.

Comment: Were you able to work this out? Shared hosting with azure data storage? I would like to do the same thing. Please reply